CTS-Tradefed isuue while building AOSP 14
I am trying to build AOSP 14. THis is my first time trying to compile AOSP. I have sucesfully downloaded, but when i try to build the AOSP. It gives the issues that some CTS tests depends upon lib "CTS-tradefed".
I tried to look over the issue, and seems like i am missing CTS-tradefed lib from my directry. I have downloaded it from android website. But i don't know where to add this in AOSP. I tied to put it in /cts/tools/ But it still is giving issues. How can i solve this.
Edit: I have downloaded android14-release.

Can you try to copy your compiled test APK to Android 14 downloaded folder? Usually if you replace it with the one under android-cts/testcases///.apk file, and give 777 permission to the folder, you should be good.
